# Is "To whom could we direct our questions to?" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, questions

Which of these sentences are proper? :

1. If we have further questions with regards to x&y, to whom could we direct our questions?
2. If we have further questions with regards to x&y, to whom could we direct our questions to?

Or is it true that both are grammatical and either one could do?

Comment: There's a horrible example of this in 'Live and Let Die' `But in this ever changing world in which we live in.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No**, the first one is grammatical, but the second one is **not**.

The reason is the repeated *to*. When you move the interrogative pronoun *whom* to the front of the question, it turns out to be the object of the preposition *to*. So moving it splits a phrase. This is OK, and you can just leave the *to* at the end.

- ***Whom** could we direct our questions **to***?

However, if you're going to use *whom* (most people would use *who*), you probably will want to [***Pied-pipe***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied-piping_with_inversion) the preposition *to* along with it, to keep the phrase together.

- ***To whom** could we direct our questions?*

What you **don't** do is copy *to whom* to the front and **also** keep *to* at the end.

- ****To whom*** could we direct our questions **to**?

Comment: Haj Ross tells me that this phenomenon is called "double-dipping".

Comment: How very amusing. If you say it, everyone kowtows, if I say it, everyone jumps on me. Why is that? Hm? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/517291/can-preposition-to-be-omitted-in-this-case/517344#517344 For whom does the bell actually toll? :)

Comment: It is worth saying that we are dealing with what might be called a 'transitional redundancy'.  English usage has been moving away from two rules: 1) that the a relative pronoun in the (indirect) object role should inflect to 'whom'; 2) that prepositions should not be left to the end of a sentence or clause (the so called 'dangling preposition').  This sentence points in both directions.  My guess is that it is spoken rather than written (and so could not have benefitted from editing).   However, I would argue that the redundant final 'to' is not strictly a a fault of grammar.

Comment: @Tuffy Written and spoken English are not necessarily the same. That said, putting in two tos is really bad. Now,when people speak fast, they sometimes do that inadvertently. If you asked them to repeat what they said, they would probably catch their own mistake. Fault of grammar? No,it is not grammar's fault, it is a speaker's mistake.

Comment: @Lambie Exactly.

Answer (score 5):

> To whom would we direct our questions?

The second **to** is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way of putting it would be *If we have further questions about x&y, who should we ask?*

Comment: '... whom should we ask?'

Answer (score 0):

> Who  could  we direct  our  questions  to?

is  also  correct  according  to  modern  grammarians.

I think  *who* is  used  more  than  *whom*  in  modern English

According  to  the  traditional  grammarians, the  correct  form  is:

To  whom could  we  direct  our  questions ?

I am  not  sure  the question  given  below  is acceptable  either  to  traditional  grammarians  or  modern grammarians

> Whom  could we  direct  our  questions  to?

The  use  of  preposition both  in the beginning  and  at  the end of  question is  not grammatical.

Comment: We  can  happily  end  a sentence  with  a  preposition.