# I wish I would and sequence of tenses

Tags: grammar, conditionals, wish-preterite

Let us suppose we want to say that we want to resume practicing a language before we forget it absolutely. So we will say:

```
I wish I would resume ... before ...
```

And what after *before*? Can we use the same pattern here - that is present conditional?

Also I am curious what conditional should be used if the sentence starts with I wish *I resumed* and I wish *I had resumed*, that is hypothetical situation (when we cannot resume) and when we regret we did not resume in the past (and now it is too late)

Comment: It's preferable to say: *"I wish I could resume my studies"* to express a form of regret in the present. If on the other hand you want to express regret in the past then: *"I wish I had resumed my studies"*. I know this doesn't answer your question, but you really should write the example sentence in full.

Comment: Just to be clear: Do we mean that we hope you will resume in the future, or do we regret that we failed to resume in the past and now we have forgotten it absolutely?

Comment: @Mar I posted my comment before I saw yours. I think we are more likely to use *hope* for the future. We'd use *wish* if we wanted to, but some obstacle made it impossible to do so.

Comment: I'd like to know how the conditional should be formulated for all the three cases: hope I'll resume in the future, regret I didn't resume and now it's late and hypothetical wish.

Comment: "**I hope** I will resume. . ." (future) and "I hope I can resume . . ." (present) are both fine. "to hope" and  "to wish" are used differently. Italian learners also mix the two up. I see nothing wrong with "**I wish** I could resume . . . " to express a strong desire in the present.

Comment: I recommend a simple online search. The first several results you get should pretty clearly explain what are commonly taught as *the four kinds of conditionals.* For example, see http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/conditionals.html . If you have more questions after that, please edit this one or create a new one. Please see the help section on this page for more information on appropriate or "good" questions. Flagging to close for want of research.

Comment: [The use of the verb **wish** indicates that the speaker wants reality to be different. As in unreal conditionals, the use of a past or past perfect tense verb indicates that the situation is impossible or unlikely. The use of **hope**, on the other hand, indicates that the speaker believes something is possible.](http://staff.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/wish.html)

Comment: Yes, please do some preliminary search online, then either edit or post a new question. Your question is not very clear, and it looks like you have just studied this form, your ideas seem to be muddled. Persevere, look at both links, these should help you. Good luck!

Comment: @Mar Yes. In reality, wish or hope may be sometimes used without regard to that kind of distinction, especially in speech, but generally there is a significant difference in denotation as you wrote just above. Of course, the line between unlikely and possible is often fuzzy, of course. There can also be a factor of agency at work. We may use "wish" if an eventuality will be determined by something other than our personal will. (So a genie who appears from a lamp you rub may be considered quite likely to grant your wish, but since you rely on the genie, we'd call it a wish!!)

Comment: The grammar of wishing is complex enough, and there are differences between BrE and AmE usage. As a British English speaker, for example, I doubt I would ever say _I wish I would/n't ..._, e.g. "_I wish I wouldn't spend so much time on ELU._" Neither can I conceive of a context in which _"I wish I resumed ..._"  is possible. I suggest editing your post to ask a single question. You might also want to consult a recommended pedagogic grammar such as Swan's _Practical English Usage_, which has a good coverage of this topic.

Comment: I think you're mistaking *would* in: **"I wish you would remember** *to take your keys before leaving the house"* for being conditional. It is not. *Would* expresses a repeated action action in the past, similar to *used to*. **I wish it would stop raining** is not conditional, it expresses an unreal situation i.e. tchrist's "counterfactuality". I cannot wish the rain to stop.

Answer (score 2):

You should not characterize any of these as “present conditional”, whatever that means.

The verb *wish* is somewhat special in English in that it typically takes a subordinate clause explicitly marked for counterfactuality.  Contrast these subordinate clauses governed by *wish* in the present tense:

- I wish he **were** here.
- I wish he **would leave**.
- I wish I **could help** you.

With these where the clause is governed by *hope* and so have no counterfactuality marked:

- I hope he **is** here.
- I hope he **leaves**.
- I hope I **can help** you.

This is the same as with *know*, whose clause is similarly unmarked:

- I know he **is** here.
- I know he **is leaving**.
- I know I **can help** you.

Instead, *wish* works more like these using *if only*, which are again explicitly marked for counterfactuality:

- If only he **were** here!
- If only he **would leave**!
- If only I **could help** you!

There are fancy grammatical terms for all these, but using them in English just confuses matters.  These is nothing “conditional” involved here.

If you are wishing for something to have been different in the past, you would have to use a past perfect to put it further in the past:

> I wish he **had called** before he showed up here.

The use of *would* in phrases like this is related to volition, not to futurity.

> I wish he **would have called** before he showed up here.

Using the simple past would be an habitual action:

> I wish he **called** before showing up here.

Please see [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/123462) for more.

Comment: I had better paraphrase my question. Can subordinate clause following __wish__ contain time expression? Can I say:  __I wish it happened before something else occurs__ ?