# "Learn to" vs "learn how to."

Tags: grammaticality

Is "I want to learn how to swim" the right expression, or should I have said so:
"I want to learn to swim."?

Comment: Answers to your question are in the following link. [learn how to"{verb} vs. learn to {verb}](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59520/learn-how-to-verb-vs-learn-to-verb).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to learn how to swim.
Swimming is something I would like to learn.
Learning to swim would be a good idea for me at this juncture.