# "Which" or "what"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, which-what

> Much of (what/which) scientists know about dinosaurs has been recently discovered.
>
> The phenomenon of (what/which) are known as corporate networks has also attracted attention.

And yes, the answer is *what*. But why?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [“Which” vs. “what” — what's the difference and when should you use one or the other?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/which-vs-what-whats-the-difference-and-when-should-you-use-one-or-the-ot)

Comment: It may be a duplicate question, but the "possible duplicate" answer doesn't explain why; it just lays down the law. And there is an answer, but it's complicated, so this will probably get closed before it gets answered.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/608581/2085).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of the clauses beginning with *what* are noun clauses. You can tell they're noun clauses because they're both the object of the preposition *of*.

- *much **of** [what scientists know about dinosaurs]*
- *the phenomenon **of** [what are known as corporate networks]*

Noun or [complement clauses](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complementtypes.pdf) can function like nouns -- as subject, direct object, or prepositional object.

There are four types of complement clauses in English, and this is the type called an embedded question (or headless relative -- they're not that different) complement. (the others are Infinitive, Gerund, and tensed That-clause.)

Embedded questions are just regular *Wh*-questions, but they have three peculiarities that mark them as subordinate clauses:

1. Embedded *Yes/No* questions use *whether* (*whether* only occurs in embedded questions)
2. Embedded questions do not [invert Subject and Verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51123/im-not-sure-what-the-right-way-is/51126#51126).
3. Embedded questions do not use *which*, but rather *what*.

It's the third peculiarity that's responsible; the normal distinction between open *what* and closed *which* is simply not available in embedded questions, just like the usual future sense of *will* is unavailable in *if*-clauses. There's a reason.

*Which* already has a role as a relative pronoun (and you can't use *what* as a relative pronoun). Relative pronouns are **Adjective** clauses, while Embedded Questions are **Noun** clauses. The purpose of an introductory marker like *what* or *that* or *which* is to indicate -- **before** it's parsed -- what kind of clause is coming up.

If *which* already marks adjective clauses, it's confusing to have another *which* that marks noun clauses. So we don't. *What* marks noun clauses and *which* doesn't, while *which* marks adjective clauses and *what* doesn't. That's all, really. It's kind of like opposing metal to colour in heraldry -- it improves clarity and avoids confusion in the signal.

Comment: "Much of what was left" is different to "much of which was left" because the first describes a thing, and the second describes an action. Does that fit into what you've described above?

Comment: The first clause is a headless relative, meaning "that which was left"; since the antecedent of the relative is missing, it's effectively a noun clause, and that's why _what_ introduces headless relatives. The second clause has a normal relative _which_, but there is a [pied-piped](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55126/is-to-whom-could-we-direct-our-questions-to-grammatical/55129#55129) NP and preposition in front of it.

Comment: Addendum; today I listened again to the late Andy Griffith's "[What it Was, Was Football](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNxLxTZHKM8)" story, and noticed that he uses a _that_ after _before_ in the clause "_before that we set up the tent,_" and maybe elsewhere as well. His accent is very rural North Carolina, but accurate, though a bit exaggerated to match the naivete of the character.

Answer (score 3):

One difference between the usage of "What" and "Which" is the difference between Noun Clauses and Adjective (Relative) Clauses.

The same confusion occurs when a student makes a sentence like:

> The information WHAT scientists know about dinosaurs is limited. = X

This sentence should be:

> WHAT scientists know about dinosaurs is limited. = Noun Clause

Or,

> The information THAT scientists know about dinosaurs is limited. =
>   Adjective Clause

Similarly, "Which" will become possible in your sentence inside an Adjective Clause. For example,

> There is an existing  body of knowledge about dinosaurs, much of WHICH has
>   recently been discovered.
>
> People are flocking to build what are known as corporate networks, the
>   phenomenon of WHICH has attracted a lot of attention.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a difficult one, watch this:

> Question: What do you know about dinosaurs?

Make it to:

> Question: What do scientists know about dinosaurs?

Answer with:

> Most of what scientists know about dinosaurs has been recently discovered.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that *which* is a relative pronoun and requires an antecedent, whereas *what* is not (at least in all Standard Englishes that I am aware of).

Comment: 'Which' is also a question where there is choice or selection from a finite number of things. 'Which one do you like, the green one, the red one or the blue one?

Comment: True, but how is that relevant to the question?