# Unnecessary use of "what"?

Tags: word-choice

I have seen usage of "what" like this:

> Depending on *what* data it receives, it will follow different
>   instruction paths.

It appears to me that use of "what" above is redundant. Doesn't

> Depending on the data it receives, it will follow different instruction paths.

convey the meaning?

Comment: It should be "on the data", not just "on data".

Comment: If it were redundant you could remove it from the sentence and it would retain the same meaning. But you haven't done that here. You substituted the word "the" for "what", which to my mind would only suggest that either word is possible, not that one is redundant.

Answer (score 5):

They're **completely** different constructions, but -- as usual -- most of the identifying marks have been rubbed off, so that it looks like one word has simply been substituted for another. Not true.

In

- *Depending on data **(that) it receives***, ...

*(that) it receives* is a [Relative clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html) modifying *data*, and the relative pronoun *that* (*which* is also OK here instead of *that*) is, as noted, optional, because the relative pronoun is not the subject of the relative clause. One could use ***the*** data just as easily, because *data* is simply a noun phrase object of the preposition *on*, and noun phrases can take articles.

On the other hand, in

- *Depending on **what data it receives***, ...

the object of the preposition on is an entire subordinate noun clause, instead of a noun phrase modified by a subordinate clause. In this case, it's an ***[Embedded Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73384/15299)***.

Embedded question clauses **can** use *what*; relative clauses **can't** use *what*. In addition, you can't add an article here; *what* already fills the determiner slot and *what the data* is ungrammatical (except, perhaps, in some bizarre scientific oath like *[what the hell?](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/thehell.html)*)

Grammar is **not** about word use; grammar is about ***Constructions***. They determine **everything**.

Comment: Great! I think I now understand why both the sentences are valid constructions. But I am not seeing how the meaning changes depending on whether or not the object is an Embedded Question :-).

Comment: It **doesn't** change. Like many, many, many other situations in English, whatever differences there may be between these constructions in some contexts neutralizes in this context. Or, as William Schwenck Gilbert put it, "This particularly rapid unintelligible patter isn't generally heard, and if it is it doesn't matter".

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not redundant.

Both sentences are grammatical. But they have different constructions and meanings.

With the noun clause

> Depending on **what data it receives**, it will follow different
>   instruction paths.

the *kind* of data is emphasized. A different kind would lead to a different path.

This is also why I think this original construction is better.

---

On the other hand, with the adjective clause

> Depending on data (that) **it receives**, it will follow different
>   instruction paths.

is more general. The *data* will dictate the paths to take, not so much the type of data.

Comment: Thank you! But if I were to say that something follows the kind of data, shouldn't I choose to be more direct -- Depending on the kind of data it receives ...

Comment: I don't agree that semantic distinction. All variations (including *"Depending on data received, it follows different paths."*) mean the same thing, which is predicated on the word *depending*. The specific grammatical structure doesn't affect that.