# what book to read & which book to read

Tags: grammar

In the absence of a clear context regarding how known or unknown is the number of books available for me to read, should I use *what book to read* or *which book to read*?

> I don't know *what* book to read (= I don't know how many books there
>   are for me to choose from.)
>
> I don't know *which* book to read (= I know how many books there are
>   for me to choose from, and choose one from that specified number.)

Are these assumptions correct or not? If not, why?

Comment: Related: *[“Which” vs. “what” — what's the difference and when should you use one or the other?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413)* and *[“Which” or “what”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73329)*.

Answer (score 1):

"what book" is quite a general question. In a bookshop the shop assistant might ask "What (kind of) book do you want? A novel, a garden book, a children's book and so on?

"which book" is always asking with reference to a special group of books. When the shop assistant points at a table with a lot of books, he might ask "Which book do you want to see?". He might as well ask "Which of these books do you want to see?"