# Can preposition "to" be omitted in this case

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses, ellipses, pied-piping

> Aston Martin’s IPO will provide further clues **to** which category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong.
>
> its context:[economist](https://www.economist.com/business/2018/09/29/makers-of-very-expensive-cars-want-to-be-luxury-goods-firms)

Grammatically,you need to have " **clues to** which..." and " **to** which... **belong** ". So is "to" double duty here？

Or it should have been:

> Aston Martin’s IPO will provide further clues to which category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong **to**.

Do you think it is acceptable or the writer made a mistake?

Comment: Similar: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/55126/191178

Comment: No,I think they are different. In this case, "to" goes with "clues",as in "clues to".So there should be an additional "to" before "which" or after "belong"

Comment: It's an error: "which category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong to" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) where the meaning is "Aston Martin’s IPO will provide further clues to the answer to the question 'Which category do ultra-expensive carmakers really belong to?'"

Comment: **Please do not try and second guess The Economist**. There is no better English-language news magazine in the world even though it is too conservative for my taste. It has the best writers and editors in the entire English-speaking world.

Comment: @Lambie That's hyperbole. The economist is pretty good,  but by nomeans infallible. They used to give Geoff Pullum ample opportunity to rib them in the THES. BillJ is right here, and you and the economist are wrong. If you think the *to* there has been pied-piped, try moving it back to the end of the sentence. You'll note the result is ungrammatical. Why did they end up in this mess? The dumbass policy of not ending a sentence with a preposition. It's always that that gets them, or avoiding "split infinitives".

Comment: belong to a category: Which category do you belong **to**? [right] **To which** category do you belong? [right] Now, let's change **clues + to** to **clues + on or about**: **Aston Martin’s IPO will provide further clues on or about the category *to which* ultra-expensive carmakers really belong**.  *clues to, on or about**. Your transformations are incorrect.

Comment: @Lambie You've changed the interrogative to a relative clause modifying the word *category*. That isn't a viable parse of the OP's sentence where *category* occurs ***after*** the interrogative phrase *to which*.

Comment: In any event, this is **not** clues to [some  thing]. As in: clues to the mystery or clues to the puzzle. 'The to which introduces a relative clause; the category to which something belongs.

Comment: @Lambie, this doesn't clarify whether there's any "double duty". While I'd concure with you, I'd add that "provide ... to ..." usually subordinates the receiver of the provision, which is the whole reason for all ya'll general confusion. As a German, I can confirm that *all* proposed variants translate rather naturally, but the prefered variant would use a preposition to introduce the subordinate clause.

Comment: Yes, it does show there is no double duty. **provide** has a direct object (clues) and the relative clause after the preposition **to** is standard: to which, for which, of which etc. relative clauses are preceded by nouns. Here, the noun is clues. The second one is an outright English mistake.

Comment: For reference, this would be "Er liefert Hinweise, *zu welcher* Kategorie er gehört", which is kind of OK. But, there's the synonyms "zu X gehören" and "X angehören", with the later inseperable. Now the funky bit is, that "zu" seems to serve double duty as well, because it's not acceptable to say "Er liefert Hinweise, welcher Kategory er angehört", perhaps because "welcher" is polysemous and commands a different interpretation when following a noun. The same argument works analoguously for English.

Comment: @vectory Translation cannot prove grammaticality of the source language. (I am a translator.)

Comment: @Lambie, but translation can provide a clue which works in the source language

Comment: @vectory You start in one and go to the other. If the first is faulty, the second should also be faulty. That's how it's done. But the L2 doesn't reveal L1.,

Comment: @Lambie, note the translation argument works against your own inner-english transpositions, likewise. My argument works analoguously, nevertheless, especially if I should have been wrong to say "not acceptable", instead of "hardly acceptable" or "unusual", since I already said *all* the translations worked.

Comment: @vectory I really do not think you know what you are talking about. There is no translation argument. backtranslation does not prove anything about L1. Sorry, but I have had enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bill J wrote:

> It's an error: "which category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong to" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) where the meaning is "Aston Martin’s IPO will provide further clues to the answer to the question 'Which category do ultra-expensive carmakers really belong to?'

Comment: There is no embedded question at all. There is **provide clues** and **belong to a category**. And, **of course**, "Please state which category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong to" = "Please state to which category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong". **to which** and **which** x does y belong **to** are semantically and grammatically equivalent. There is "no clues to"

Comment: @Lambie So, in your opinion, what kind of phrase is 'to which category they belong', which you believe is a constituent in the original sentence, if it is not an interrogative clause?

Comment: to which they belong is a preposition followed by a relative pronoun and clause. These structures are typical in formal English: They man with whom they spoke. As opposed  to informal or spoken English: The man they spoke to.

Comment: @Lambie That would normlly be considered a relative clause. But that interpretation isn't available here, because ultraexpensve carmakers can't be conceived of as belonging to the category *clue*! [However, that would be entriely grammatical, and maybe that's why the sentence kind of sounds ok ..., even though that' not what's meant]

Comment: How many times do I have to say it? There is no "clues to something". I find clues. [no to]. I find clues to which you object. That is exactly the same structure here. Your interpretation regarding a *mistake* is based on the idea that this should be: clues  to [some thing]. That is not the case here. There is no noun after **to**, because the clause is: **to which** [blah blah blah] belong.

Comment: But if the "to" goes with belong (as it should, belong doesn't take a direct object)  there's nothing linking the first phrase to the second.  Both phrasings are awfully clumsy IMHO.    FWIW, I would have written "Aston Martin’s IPO will provide further clues *as* to which category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong.", or rewritten it totally.

Comment: @BlokeDownThePub Typically, a noun precedes a "to which"-type of construction. The man suggested answers to which the questions really applied.  There is no "link".

Comment: @BlokeDownThePub You’re right. There is no link there. The *wh*-clause here is not a relative clause, it’s a subordinate interrogative one. And you’re right that it needs something to be a complement of. The idiom *have a clue* (which normally occurs with a negative word) will take interrogatives, but the word *clues* in the phrase *provide clues* won’t, and as you note needs a preposition to link it to one.

Answer (score 0):

**Clues and prepositions**

Let’s look at some examples of the use of *clue/s* from the [Cambridge Dictionary on-line]:

*The police tried to reconstruct the crime using…**clues** that they had found*. [No preposition]

*The police found a vital **clue to** the girl's disappearance…* [Preposition, **to**]

*He pored over the letter searching for **clues about** the writer.* [Preposition, **about**]

**Let’s change the preposition**

So, as *clue* can take *about* as an alternative to the preposition *to*, we can exchange the prepositions to get a clearer idea of the role of *to* in the sentence without changing either the meaning or the grammatical structure:

> Aston Martin’s IPO will provide further clues **about** which category
>   ultra-expensive carmakers really belong.

Here the clues are about *“which category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong”*.

But surely “ultra-expensive carmarkers really belong **to** a category”.

**If so, it would appear that the journalist writing in the *Economist* made a mistake.**

How awful! I once made one myself.

Comment: Just because clues **can take** the prepositions to, about, on does not at all mean that here it is: "clues to [noun]". The police found some vital clues. They belonged to various categories. The vital clues found by police belonged to several categories. The OP's is:  clues to which category they belong.

Comment: @Lambie — I initially thought you right as the two "tos" sounds clumsy (and I certainly haven't downvoted your answer), but I cannot see my way through the following: "Clues to X", X="which category they belong". Is X grammatical — can you have belong and category without a preposition? If, for example, you make X into a sentence by adding "do" — "Which category do they belong" it lacks the preposition "to". (I appreciate you can use belong without a preposition — I do not feel I belong here, take me back to SE Biology. But that is not what we have here.)

Comment: David, please, bear with me:  You cannot see your way through: "Clues to X", X="which category they belong" because the parse is: |provide clues| + "to which strand the DNA belongs"(Is my biology right?) :)

Comment: @Lambie — One might quibble with the Biology, but it is not important in this context. The problem remains the same: euphony gives one answer, analysis gives another.  It would be good if some other grammarians weighed in on this. I’m prepared to be proved wrong.

Comment: My joke about biology was to show (you) that the structure of my sentence and the OP's sentence are exactly the same. You ignored, in fact, what I actually said. One last attempt: The implied parsing by you, Bill J and Araucaria is mistaken: There are not two to prepositions. There is "belong to" but there is **no "clues to"** [thing]. It's **provide clues** and **to which [rest of clause]**

Comment: @Lambie Are you trying to say  "to which [rest of clause]" is an apposition clause ？

Comment: @Robbyzhu Absolutely not. It is a relative clause with an introductory preposition.

Answer (score -1):

X will provide clues. [**no to**]

These cars belong **to** a category. [**belong to** a category]

**X will provide clues to which category the cars belong.**

**One is hard pressed to concoct a mistake in *The Economist*'s sentence:**

Aston Martin’s IPO will provide further clues // to which category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong.

The parse is shown by the slash

**belong to a category** is a verb plus a prepositional phrase.

**The sentence does not say**:

**Clues to** a category. [clues to plus a noun]. That parse here would be wrong.

**provide clues** is a verb plus a direct object.

to which category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong=

a relative clause introduced by the preposition **to** followed by a relative clause introduced by **which.**

Typical of formal English.

[placement of prepositions](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/preposition-placement-relative-clauses/)

Just one example from that link:

INFORMAL: Is that the man (who) she arrived with?
FORMAL: Is that the man with whom she arrived?

Comment: "Clues" doesn't take a *to* unless there is a following complement. There is one in the Economist sentence. Try substituting with a different intertogative clause * "They will provide clues what happened" <--- Why's that ungrammatical? No "to", that's why!

Comment: @Araucaria It is most definitely not ungrammatical. There are two separate issues: **provide clues** + **belong to a category**. The parse is not:  **provide clues to which etc.**

Comment: But every phrase in a sentence has some kind of grammatical function (subject/object/complement of a noun/complement of a preposition etc) What function/grammatical relations do you believe that the constituent *to which category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong* has, then? I can't just float in mid-air.

Comment: /to which category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong/ **to** is a preposition followed by a relative pronoun (which) in a relative clause. The word clues here is not followed by a noun: clues to the mystery/clues to the puzzle. It is: clues to which you object. ha ha

Comment: That would make it a pied-piped relative clause. However, that isn't the meaning the Economist article has, as I tried to explain in my comment in our discussion under the question. By the way [here is some discussion of The Economist by maybe its greatest fan](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=21048)

Comment: @Araucaria Oh, so that isn't the meaning? You are a hoot. And this: Aston Martin’s IPO will provide further clues to which category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong to.= [buzzer]. Your reading depends on **clues to [some thing]**.

Comment: Yes, that’s tight. That is the correct parse. The car makers belong to a category, not clues. And the clues are clues as to which category this is.

Comment: The two categories there being "couture" or "clunker".